Integrals of the form $\mathcal{P}\int_{-1}^1dx \frac{N(x)}{(x-x_0)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$
In the context of https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9805477, one finds $\mathcal{P}\int_{-1}^1dx \frac{N(x)}{(x-x_0)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ where N is an anaytic function of x. I care about the case with $-1<x_0<0$ and $x_0<-1$.
I wish to study this expression numerically and analytically. A first massaging I did to the integral was to subtract its singularity and then taylor expand $\mathcal{N}(x)-\mathcal{N}(x_0)$ to cancel the simple pole and have analytic known integrals of the form $\int_{-1}^1dx\frac{(x-x_0)^n}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\mathcal{P}\int_{-1}^1dx\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{1}{x_0-x}\mathcal{N}(x)=\\
&=\mathcal{P}\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x_0-x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}[\mathcal{N}(x)-\mathcal{N}(x_0)]+\mathcal{P}\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{x_0-x}\frac{\mathcal{N}(x_0)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
This approach solution does not work numerically as $x_0$ approaches the boundary of -1 the Taylor expansion stops converging in the whole integral interval.
As the link I presented suggested this appears in the context of scattering theory in HEP.
I once found a somewhat old article discussing integrals of this form but ended up losing it. I was looking for ways to deal analytically and numerically with these types of integrals. If you knew some good reference on it I would be appreciated.
